# How to plot time of UTC data in x-axis using Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have following data from a file . I want to plot my other data w.r.t this time. I want to plot this data on x-axis. How to do it?
    05:39:07:79 
   05:39:08:00 
   05:39:08:20 
   05:39:08:40 
05:39:08:59 
05:39:08:79 
05:39:09:00 
05:39:09:20 
05:39:09:40 
05:39:09:59 
05:39:09:79 
05:39:10:00 
05:39:10:20 
05:39:10:40

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot time series in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079143/how-to-plot-time-series-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for responding . My data is in text file and it is in UTC format ,no need to modify. How to plot using loop for the length of time. Using range and length how to plot?

Comment: You are basically asking people to write code for you. Your problem is not specific enough and any answer would not be useful for anyone other than you. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask