# Plot time series with discontinous interval

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some data. The data is a list of tuples (`date, value`), sorted by `date`. This list is created from a list of dictionaries that is not ordered by date and the interval covered is not continuous, that is, not all of dates between first and last date have entries. I chose list of tuples to assure that each `value` is paired to the correct `date`. From a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079143/how-to-plot-time-series-in-python), I saw that is possible to create a time series (in a continuous interval) using numpy. Then I tried to create an array using the dates from the list of tuples:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_by_date(delay_list_tech):
    """
    plot data from delay_list_tech
    input: delay_list_tech - list of dictionaries
    """   

    # create list of tuples
    answer_row = []
    answer_list = []
    for row in delay_list_tech:
        y_val = row['delay_days']

        dummy_date = row['effective_date']
        x_val = dummy_date.split('-')
        x_val_year = int(x_val[0])
        x_val_mont = int(x_val[1])
        x_val_day = int(x_val[2])
        x_date = datetime.date(x_val_year, x_val_mont, x_val_day)

        answer_row.append(x_date)
        answer_row.append(y_val)
        dummy_row = answer_row.copy()
        answer_list.append(tuple(dummy_row))
        answer_row.clear()

    # sorting
    answer_list.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[0], reverse=False)

    # error on generating array for x axis
    x = np.array(answer_list[idx][0] for idx in range(len(answer_list)))
```

Is it possible to create the time series using a non-continuous data source?

Thanks in avance,

Tiago

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Yes, it is possible to create a time series with non-continuous data. What do you want to do with missing data? Filter it: use a mask, interpolate it: use `np.interp1d`, replace with a value (e.g. 0): use a mask

Comment: Kind of nit-picky, but all time series data like this is "non-continuous" in that it's data sampled at discrete times.  You might have more luck searching for "non-uniformly sampled"

Comment: Hi Mstaino, thanks for answering. I wanted to make sure that the question would be correctly expressed; then I wrote it a bit longer than usual here.

About the missing data, I don't have intention on dealing with it, because I'm working with data on document publishing. The system that publishes the documents behaves naturally in a non-continuous way.

Thank you for the hints.

Comment: Ok John, thanks for you anwser.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what trouble you're running into since you didn't post any example data. However, your code is doing a lot of unnecessary things. Here's a cleaned up, functioning version:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_by_date(delay_list_tech):
    """plot data from delay_list_tech
    input: delay_list_tech - list of dictionaries
    """   
    # create list of tuples
    answer_list = []
    for row in delay_list_tech:
        x_val = row['effective_date'].split('-')
        x_val_year = int(x_val[0])
        x_val_mont = int(x_val[1])
        x_val_day = int(x_val[2])
        x_date = datetime.date(x_val_year, x_val_mont, x_val_day)
        answer_list.append((x_date, row['delay_days']))

    # sorting
    answer_list.sort()

    # error on generating array for x axis
    x = np.array([row[0] for row in answer_list])
    y = np.array([row[1] for row in answer_list])

    plt.plot(x, y)
```

Testing it out:

```
# some test data
d = [
    ('1991-01-15', 47),
    ('1995-04-14', 10),
    ('1987-01-12', 99),
    ('2001-03-19', 41),
    ('1999-11-03', 9),
]

# convert to list of dictionaries, as per OP's question
d = [dict(zip(('effective_date', 'delay_days'), row)) for row in d]

# plot
plot_by_date(d)
```

Output:

[image]